# How to parse the wsdl in xcode

Tags: iphone

Can any bode tell me the link or code to parse the wsdl file in xcode ?
webservices that are built in .net

Answer (score 2):

a tool named  **WSDL2Objc** there.It will get input as wsdl file and returns Objective-c client stub for the given wsdl.

You can find the instructions here.
        http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions

Also download the tool from here
    http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/downloads/list