# XCode 4.3 with WCF

Tags: xcode, ios4

I'm trying to figure out how to design an iOS app that would connect to a WCF service. I've looked around and WSMakeStubs looks like it worked way back but I cannot find that anywhere in XCode 4.3 and I can't find a place to download it. I've downloaded the command line tools and then more command line tools but it doesn't seem to be included.

I've tried [How to parse the wsdl in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013489/how-to-parse-the-wsdl-in-xcode) but the app doesn't seem to work. I browsw to the URL, select a folder and click Parse. It says Finished but doesn't generate any .h files so I am not sure what I am doing wrong with it...

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it. Went to my Apple Developer login and went to old downloads. Then installed XCode 3 and it is included with it. Hopefully now I can continue with the WCF app.

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode